# Enumerate Text Values in Power-Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a column in my table that has some text values (*input*) which I would like to convert to numbers (*output*) for each unique text value, so that I can do some regression analysis:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| AOP | 1 |
| AOS | 2 |
| AOS | 2 |
| AOS | 2 |
| AOP | 1 |
| null | 0 or null |
| AOP | 1 |

I initially tried to do this do this with several `Transform: Replace Values` steps, however I don't know how to:

- make this flexible to different numbers of unique values (not hardcode 3 replacements but handle `n` where `n` is the number of unique values in *input*)
- repeat this for many columns of my table
- avoid looping as far as possible

What's a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is add custom column with below formula, and do that for each column you care to apply it to, using the value of each text character to generate a unique number

```
= try 
 List.Accumulate(Text.ToList([Input]), "", (state, current)=>
 state&Number.ToText(Character.ToNumber(current), "0000")) otherwise null
```

this would transform all column's text into unique numbers, replacing the original data:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Function = (x) => try  List.Accumulate(Text.ToList(x), "", (state, current)=> state&Number.ToText(Character.ToNumber(current), "0000")) otherwise null,
TransformList = List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_ , Function}),
Output = Table.TransformColumns(Source, TransformList)
in Output
```

this would transform all column's text into unique numbers, appending the new columns to existing columns:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Function = (x) => try List.Accumulate(Text.ToList(x), "", (state, current)=> state&Number.ToText(Character.ToNumber(current), "0000")) otherwise null,
TransformList = List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_ , Function}),
Output = Table.TransformColumns(Source, TransformList),
Numericals=Table.RenameColumns( Output, List.Zip( { Table.ColumnNames( Output), List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Output), each _ &"number") } ) ),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),{"Index"},Table.AddIndexColumn(Numericals, "Index2", 0, 1),{"Index2"},"Tabl2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Tabl2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Tabl2", Table.ColumnNames( Numericals),Table.ColumnNames( Numericals)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Tabl2",{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: This is great; is there a way to scale the numbers to single digits? I was thinking take the numerical output list and apply a ranking transformation - although I can't figure out how to do this in place?

Comment: If AAA is in InputA column and AAA is also in Input B column, do they have the same output number? If so, its likely as simple as unpivot, remove duplicates, add index, merge back to unpivoted table and then repivot