# Convert categorical variables to numeric PowerQuery

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, categorical-data, m

I have a number of columns in my table which have text values that fall into categories - e.g. column "ABC" has 9000 rows but every row must have a value in the set {"A","B","C"}. Other columns like Gender have "M"/"F"/null

For each column, I'd like to convert it into an integer list in-place - so A:1, B:2, C:3 etc.

I've been trying out using `List.Distinct` to extract the values to a temp table, adding an index column to that and using a join to transform the initial column based on that mapping in the temp table. However this seems slow and I'm not sure how to run this over all columns in my table (or at least `Table.ColumnsOfType(Source, {type nullable text})` to select the categorical columns...).

Any suggestions?

#### Before

| Gender | Fruit | [...] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | Cat |  |
| F | Dog |  |
| M | Lemon |  |
| M | Dog |  |
| M | Lemon |  |
| null | Cat |  |
| M | Dog |  |

#### After

| Gender | Fruit | [...] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 2 |  |
| 2 | 3 |  |
| 2 | 2 |  |
| 2 | 3 |  |
| null | 1 |  |
| 2 | 2 |  |

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66010168/6609896

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerQuery, this seems to work for any number of columns

Replace all nulls with something else, here +=+

Add Index

Unpivot

Remove duplicates

Group, add index to each group

[image]

Merge back into original and expand

Repivot

Remove extra columns

Before and After:

[image]

Full code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,null,"+=+",Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(Source)),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

// derive a table of replacements
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Attribute", "Value"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Attribute"}, {{"GRP", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index2", 1, 1), type table}}),
#"Expanded GRP" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "GRP", {"Value", "Index2"}, {"Value", "Index2"}),

//replace originals
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute", "Value"},#"Expanded GRP",{"Attribute", "Value"},"EG",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "EG", {"Index2"}, {"Index2"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Table1",{"Value"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Index2", List.Sum),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns1"
```

Comment: Fantastic! One small hitch; is there a way to exclude some columns (I only want to run this on the text columns `Table.ColumnsOfType(Source, {type nullable text})`, numeric/date/... columns I want to leave as they were). I could just replace column values with Source by name, but it would be nice to avoid doing the calculation on them just to overwrite it. Otherwise perfect!

Comment: I would unpivot, filter the rows you want to leave alone based on column name, save that step, filter the rows you want to change based on column name, process as above instead of against all columns, then append the two before the re-pivot